# How to handle in class component passed additional parameters from parent to child event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent class component that should handle child's component `onChange` event. This is the class method that does that:

```
editTopic(index, value) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const class = {...prevState.class};
      class.topic =
        [...class.topic.slice(0, index), value, ...class.topic.slice(index +1)];
      const newClass = {...prevState.class, class};
      return {class: newClass};

    })
  }
```

I am passing this method as a prop to a first child like this:

```
editTopic={(index, value) => this.editTopic(index, value)}
```

I am passing further down this prop all the way to a child component where I can get the `index`. There I am using this function callback like this to give it `index` and pass it down to `select` component that is going to give it a `value`:

```
<AutocompleteSelect handleChange={() => editTopic(index)}/>
```

And in `AutocompleteSelect` component I am using this callback like this in the `onChange` handler:

```
onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange(event.target.value)}
```

But, this is not working, how should I pass props like this properly, without having `AutocompleteSelect` component knowing which `index` should be passed?

**Update**

I have tried by changing the class method to a currying method like this:

```
editTema(index) {
    return value => {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        const class = {...prevState.class};
        class.topic = [...class.topic.slice(0, index), value, ...class.topic.slice(index +1)];
        const newClass = {...prevState.class, class};
        return {class: newClass};

      })
    }
  }
```

Then I am passing it down like this:

```
editTopic ={(index) => this.editTopic(index)}
```

And then in the child component that is passing the handler to `AutocompleteSelect` to this:

```
handleChange={editTema(index)}
```

And finally in `AutocompleteSelect` to this:

```
onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange(event.target.value)}
```

But, it is still not changing the state of the class component, I don't see in the console that the function is even called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
editTopic={(index) => (value) => this.editTopic(index, value)}
```

then

```
<AutocompleteSelect handleChange={editTopic(index)}/>
```

lastly

```
onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange(event.target.value)}
```

---

But it is not a good pattern, as you may notice for someone who are not familiar with your code, he probably cannot easily figure out which value should be provided in certain layer. Besides, in future, you will figure out it is quite difficult to switch to `react-hooks`.

I would suggest passing the parameter instead.

```
editTopic={(index, value) => this.editTopic(index, value)}
```

then

```
<AutocompleteSelect handleChange={editTopic} index={index}/>
```

lastly

```
const { handleChange, index } = this.props;
...
onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange(index, event.target.value)}
```

Comment: I have tried your first approach but it didn't work for me. Method was not even called. I have updated the question with new code. And I would like to avoid using index as a prop in the Autocomplete component so that I can reuse it in places where I won't be using index as well

Comment: Just found out, that the select component event value is not in the target property but in the event.value. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing a **Handler** down from a Parent Component to Child Component,
you should be passing a **reference** to the handler and not the function call actually.

So in your case when passing `editTopic()` you should just be passing

```
<Component editTopic = {this.editTopic}></Component>
```